# Training a spam filter based on Mailman moderator's actions?

Tags: spam, spam-filter, mailman

I'm planning a Mailman server, and looking for a good way to enable list moderators train a spam filter (likely to be either spamassassin or dspam).  Has anyone come up with a good way to run training based on list moderator's decisions?  Currently I don't have any better strategies than asking list moderators to forward spams one by one to a training address, which seems laborious and most likely to be inconsistently applied.

Any ideas?

I am aware of https://bugs.launchpad.net/mailman/+bug/558292 .  I'm hoping someone has a better approach.

Comment: Could the down-voter provide some explanation please?

Answer (score -2):

http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Plugins/Antispam might come in useful or, if not using Dovecot, using some self made scripting with e.g. incrontab.

Comment: I use that module for my private mail server.  It's useful for initiating spam training based on movement on of messages between mailboxes.  In this case though I want the trigger to be based on actions in mailman, by a user who would presumably not have a mailbox on the list server.  The actions would be taken through mailman's web interface, or in some cases by instructions to mailman given through email.